# how to resize the dialog generated by "ctools-use-modal" class of ctool modal functionality?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I want to resize the popup dialog box, appears when I used ctool modal functionality. I have gone through a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ctools-modal-jquery-dialog.patch) , but don't know how to apply it.

I also follow one this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231446/automatically-resize-jquery-ui-dialog-to-the-width-of-the-content-loaded-by-ajax), but is of no worth. My concern is to change the size of dialog box appears in [this link](https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7).

below is my code, that needs to expect some modification for resizing for dialog box. please help, i got struck here completely.

```
/**
 * @file
 *
 * Implement a modal form.
 *
 * @see modal.inc for documentation.
 *
 * This javascript relies on the CTools ajax responder.
 */

(function ($) {
  // Make sure our objects are defined.
  Drupal.CTools = Drupal.CTools || {};
  Drupal.CTools.Modal = Drupal.CTools.Modal || {};

  /**
   * Display the modal
   *
   * @todo -- document the settings.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.show = function(choice) {
    var opts = {};

    if (choice && typeof choice == 'string' && Drupal.settings[choice]) {
      // This notation guarantees we are actually copying it.
      $.extend(true, opts, Drupal.settings[choice]);
    }
    else if (choice) {
      $.extend(true, opts, choice);
    }

    var defaults = {
      modalTheme: 'CToolsModalDialog',
      throbberTheme: 'CToolsModalThrobber',
      animation: 'show',
      animationSpeed: 'fast',
      modalSize: {
        type: 'scale',
        width: .8,
        height: .8,
        addWidth: 0,
        addHeight: 0,
        // How much to remove from the inner content to make space for the
        // theming.
        contentRight: 25,
        contentBottom: 45
      },
      modalOptions: {
        opacity: .55,
        background: '#fff'
      }
    };

    var settings = {};
    $.extend(true, settings, defaults, Drupal.settings.CToolsModal, opts);

    if (Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings && Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings != settings) {
      Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal.remove();
      Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal = null;
    }

    Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings = settings;

    var resize = function(e) {
      // When creating the modal, it actually exists only in a theoretical
      // place that is not in the DOM. But once the modal exists, it is in the
      // DOM so the context must be set appropriately.
      var context = e ? document : Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal;

      if (Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.type == 'scale') {
        var width = $(window).width() * Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.width;
        var height = $(window).height() * Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.height;
      }
      else {
        var width = Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.width;
        var height = Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.height;
      }

      // Use the additionol pixels for creating the width and height.
      $('div.ctools-modal-content', context).css({
        'width': width + Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.addWidth + 'px',
        'height': height + Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.addHeight + 'px'
      });
      $('div.ctools-modal-content .modal-content', context).css({
        'width': (width - Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.contentRight) + 'px',
        'height': (height - Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.modalSize.contentBottom) + 'px'
      });
    }

    if (!Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal) {
      Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal = $(Drupal.theme(settings.modalTheme));
      if (settings.modalSize.type == 'scale') {
        $(window).bind('resize', resize);
      }
    }

    resize();

    $('span.modal-title', Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal).html(Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.loadingText);
    Drupal.CTools.Modal.modalContent(Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal, settings.modalOptions, settings.animation, settings.animationSpeed);
    $('#modalContent .modal-content').html(Drupal.theme(settings.throbberTheme));
  };

  /**
   * Hide the modal
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.dismiss = function() {
    if (Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal) {
      Drupal.CTools.Modal.unmodalContent(Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Provide the HTML to create the modal dialog.
   */
  Drupal.theme.prototype.CToolsModalDialog = function () {
    var html = ''
    html += '  <div id="ctools-modal">'
    html += '    <div class="ctools-modal-content">' // panels-modal-content
    html += '      <div class="modal-header">';
    html += '        <a class="close" href="#">';
    html +=            Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.closeText + Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.closeImage;
    html += '        </a>';
    html += '        <span id="modal-title" class="modal-title">&nbsp;</span>';
    html += '      </div>';
    html += '      <div id="modal-content" class="modal-content">';
    html += '      </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '  </div>';

    return html;
  }

  /**
   * Provide the HTML to create the throbber.
   */
  Drupal.theme.prototype.CToolsModalThrobber = function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '  <div id="modal-throbber">';
    html += '    <div class="modal-throbber-wrapper">';
    html +=        Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.throbber;
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '  </div>';

    return html;
  };

  /**
   * Figure out what settings string to use to display a modal.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.getSettings = function (object) {
    var match = $(object).attr('class').match(/ctools-modal-(\S+)/);
    if (match) {
      return match[1];
    }
  }

  /**
   * Click function for modals that can be cached.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.clickAjaxCacheLink = function () {
    Drupal.CTools.Modal.show(Drupal.CTools.Modal.getSettings(this));
    return Drupal.CTools.AJAX.clickAJAXCacheLink.apply(this);
  };

  /**
   * Handler to prepare the modal for the response
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.clickAjaxLink = function () {
    Drupal.CTools.Modal.show(Drupal.CTools.Modal.getSettings(this));
    return false;
  };

  /**
   * Submit responder to do an AJAX submit on all modal forms.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.submitAjaxForm = function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var form = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() { Drupal.CTools.AJAX.ajaxSubmit(form, url); }, 1);
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Bind links that will open modals to the appropriate function.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.ZZCToolsModal = {
    attach: function(context) {
      // Bind links
      // Note that doing so in this order means that the two classes can be
      // used together safely.
      /*
       * @todo remimplement the warm caching feature
      $('a.ctools-use-modal-cache:not(.ctools-use-modal-processed)', context)
        .addClass('ctools-use-modal-processed')
        .click(Drupal.CTools.Modal.clickAjaxCacheLink)
        .each(function () {
          Drupal.CTools.AJAX.warmCache.apply(this);
        });
        */

      $('a.ctools-use-modal:not(.ctools-use-modal-processed)', context)
        .addClass('ctools-use-modal-processed')
        .click(Drupal.CTools.Modal.clickAjaxLink)
        .each(function () {
          // Create a drupal ajax object
          var element_settings = {};
          if ($(this).attr('href')) {
            element_settings.url = $(this).attr('href');
            element_settings.event = 'click';
            element_settings.progress = { type: 'throbber' };
          }
          var base = $(this).attr('href');
          Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax(base, this, element_settings);

          // Attach the display behavior to the ajax object
        }
      );

      // Bind buttons
      $('input.ctools-use-modal:not(.ctools-use-modal-processed), button.ctools-use-modal:not(.ctools-use-modal-processed)', context)
        .addClass('ctools-use-modal-processed')
        .click(Drupal.CTools.Modal.clickAjaxLink)
        .each(function() {
          var button = this;
          var element_settings = {};

          // AJAX submits specified in this manner automatically submit to the
          // normal form action.
          element_settings.url = Drupal.CTools.Modal.findURL(this);
          element_settings.event = 'click';

          var base = $(this).attr('id');
          Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax(base, this, element_settings);

          // Make sure changes to settings are reflected in the URL.
          $('.' + $(button).attr('id') + '-url').change(function() {
            Drupal.ajax[base].options.url = Drupal.CTools.Modal.findURL(button);
          });
        });

      // Bind our custom event to the form submit
      $('#modal-content form:not(.ctools-use-modal-processed)', context)
        .addClass('ctools-use-modal-processed')
        .each(function() {
          $('input[type=submit], button', this).click(function() {
            this.form.clk = this;
          });

          var element_settings = {};

          element_settings.url = $(this).attr('action');
          element_settings.event = 'submit';
          element_settings.progress = { 'type': 'throbber' }
          var base = $(this).attr('id');

          Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax(base, this, element_settings);
          Drupal.ajax[base].form = $(this);
        });
    }
  };

  // The following are implementations of AJAX responder commands.

  /**
   * AJAX responder command to place HTML within the modal.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal_display = function(ajax, response, status) {
    $('#modal-title').html(response.title);
    $('#modal-content').html(response.output);
    Drupal.attachBehaviors();
  }

  /**
   * AJAX responder command to dismiss the modal.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal_dismiss = function(command) {
    Drupal.CTools.Modal.dismiss();
    $('link.ctools-temporary-css').remove();
  }

  /**
   * Display loading
   */
  //Drupal.CTools.AJAX.commands.modal_loading = function(command) {
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal_loading = function(command) {
    Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal_display({
      output: Drupal.theme(Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.throbberTheme),
      title: Drupal.CTools.Modal.currentSettings.loadingText
    });
  }

  /**
   * Find a URL for an AJAX button.
   *
   * The URL for this gadget will be composed of the values of items by
   * taking the ID of this item and adding -url and looking for that
   * class. They need to be in the form in order since we will
   * concat them all together using '/'.
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.findURL = function(item) {
    var url = '';
    var url_class = '.' + $(item).attr('id') + '-url';
    $(url_class).each(
      function() {
        if (url && $(this).val()) {
          url += '/';
        }
        url += $(this).val();
      });
    return url;
  };


  /**
   * modalContent
   * @param content string to display in the content box
   * @param css obj of css attributes
   * @param animation (fadeIn, slideDown, show)
   * @param speed (valid animation speeds slow, medium, fast or # in ms)
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.modalContent = function(content, css, animation, speed) {
    // If our animation isn't set, make it just show/pop
    if (!animation) {
      animation = 'show';
    }
    else {
      // If our animation isn't "fadeIn" or "slideDown" then it always is show
      if (animation != 'fadeIn' && animation != 'slideDown') {
        animation = 'show';
      }
    }

    if (!speed) {
      speed = 'fast';
    }

    // Build our base attributes and allow them to be overriden
    css = jQuery.extend({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '0px',
      margin: '0px',
      background: '#000',
      opacity: '.55'
    }, css);

    // Add opacity handling for IE.
    css.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (100 * css.opacity) + ')';
    content.hide();

    // if we already ahve a modalContent, remove it
    if ( $('#modalBackdrop')) $('#modalBackdrop').remove();
    if ( $('#modalContent')) $('#modalContent').remove();

    // position code lifted from http://www.quirksmode.org/viewport/compatibility.html
    if (self.pageYOffset) { // all except Explorer
    var wt = self.pageYOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) { // Explorer 6 Strict
      var wt = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    } else if (document.body) { // all other Explorers
      var wt = document.body.scrollTop;
    }

    // Get our dimensions

    // Get the docHeight and (ugly hack) add 50 pixels to make sure we dont have a *visible* border below our div
    var docHeight = $(document).height() + 50;
    var docWidth = $(document).width();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if( docHeight < winHeight ) docHeight = winHeight;

    // Create our divs
    $('body').append('<div id="modalBackdrop" style="z-index: 1000; display: none;"></div><div id="modalContent" style="z-index: 1001; position: absolute;">' + $(content).html() + '</div>');

    // Keyboard and focus event handler ensures focus stays on modal elements only
    modalEventHandler = function( event ) {
      target = null;
      if ( event ) { //Mozilla
        target = event.target;
      } else { //IE
        event = window.event;
        target = event.srcElement;
      }

      var parents = $(target).parents().get();
      for (var i in $(target).parents().get()) {
        var position = $(parents[i]).css('position');
        if (position == 'absolute' || position == 'fixed') {
          return true;
        }
      }
      if( $(target).filter('*:visible').parents('#modalContent').size()) {
        // allow the event only if target is a visible child node of #modalContent
        return true;
      }
      if ( $('#modalContent')) $('#modalContent').get(0).focus();
      return false;
    };
    $('body').bind( 'focus', modalEventHandler );
    $('body').bind( 'keypress', modalEventHandler );

    // Create our content div, get the dimensions, and hide it
    var modalContent = $('#modalContent').css('top','-1000px');
    var mdcTop = wt + ( winHeight / 2 ) - (  modalContent.outerHeight() / 2);
    var mdcLeft = ( winWidth / 2 ) - ( modalContent.outerWidth() / 2);
    $('#modalBackdrop').css(css).css('top', 0).css('height', docHeight + 'px').css('width', docWidth + 'px').show();
    modalContent.css({top: mdcTop + 'px', left: mdcLeft + 'px'}).hide()[animation](speed);

    // Bind a click for closing the modalContent
    modalContentClose = function(){close(); return false;};
    $('.close').bind('click', modalContentClose);

    // Close the open modal content and backdrop
    function close() {
      // Unbind the events
      $(window).unbind('resize',  modalContentResize);
      $('body').unbind( 'focus', modalEventHandler);
      $('body').unbind( 'keypress', modalEventHandler );
      $('.close').unbind('click', modalContentClose);
      $(document).trigger('CToolsDetachBehaviors', $('#modalContent'));

      // Set our animation parameters and use them
      if ( animation == 'fadeIn' ) animation = 'fadeOut';
      if ( animation == 'slideDown' ) animation = 'slideUp';
      if ( animation == 'show' ) animation = 'hide';

      // Close the content
      modalContent.hide()[animation](speed);

      // Remove the content
      $('#modalContent').remove();
      $('#modalBackdrop').remove();
    };

    // Move and resize the modalBackdrop and modalContent on resize of the window
     modalContentResize = function(){
      // Get our heights
      var docHeight = $(document).height();
      var docWidth = $(document).width();
      var winHeight = $(window).height();
      var winWidth = $(window).width();
      if( docHeight < winHeight ) docHeight = winHeight;

      // Get where we should move content to
      var modalContent = $('#modalContent');
      var mdcTop = ( winHeight / 2) - (  modalContent.outerHeight() / 2);
      var mdcLeft = ( winWidth / 2 ) - ( modalContent.outerWidth() / 2);

      // Apply the changes
      $('#modalBackdrop').css('height', docHeight + 'px').css('width', docWidth + 'px').show();
      modalContent.css('top', mdcTop + 'px').css('left', mdcLeft + 'px').show();
    };
    $(window).bind('resize', modalContentResize);

    $('#modalContent').focus();
  };

  /**
   * unmodalContent
   * @param content (The jQuery object to remove)
   * @param animation (fadeOut, slideUp, show)
   * @param speed (valid animation speeds slow, medium, fast or # in ms)
   */
  Drupal.CTools.Modal.unmodalContent = function(content, animation, speed)
  {
    // If our animation isn't set, make it just show/pop
    if (!animation) { var animation = 'show'; } else {
      // If our animation isn't "fade" then it always is show
      if (( animation != 'fadeOut' ) && ( animation != 'slideUp')) animation = 'show';
    }
    // Set a speed if we dont have one
    if ( !speed ) var speed = 'fast';

    // Unbind the events we bound
    $(window).unbind('resize', modalContentResize);
    $('body').unbind('focus', modalEventHandler);
    $('body').unbind('keypress', modalEventHandler);
    $('.close').unbind('click', modalContentClose);
    $(document).trigger('CToolsDetachBehaviors', $('#modalContent'));

    // jQuery magic loop through the instances and run the animations or removal.
    content.each(function(){
      if ( animation == 'fade' ) {
        $('#modalContent').fadeOut(speed,function(){$('#modalBackdrop').fadeOut(speed, function(){$(this).remove();});$(this).remove();});
      } else {
        if ( animation == 'slide' ) {
          $('#modalContent').slideUp(speed,function(){$('#modalBackdrop').slideUp(speed, function(){$(this).remove();});$(this).remove();});
        } else {
          $('#modalContent').remove();$('#modalBackdrop').remove();
        }
      }
    });
  };

$(function() {
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.modal_display = Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal_display;
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.modal_dismiss = Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal_dismiss;
});

})(jQuery);
```